# dart flutter gray screen in apk and on the simulator everything is ok

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I ran into such a problem at the application development stage.

The problem is that in the emulator it shows the result and everything is fine, but in the phone where I installed the APK it does not work correctly, it shows a gray screen, which means an error. This screen worked until I connected it with supposedly bacon (I made my own JsonString file). Let me know if you have any questions for me

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

here is the mainscreen code:

```
`import 'package:dromis/feature/common/dr_app_bar_bottom.dart';
import 'package:dromis/feature/common/dr_bgr_for_main.dart';
import 'package:dromis/feature/common/dr_colors.dart';
import 'package:dromis/feature/common/dr_app_bar.dart';

import 'package:dromis/feature/dashboard/dashboard_screen.dart';
import 'package:dromis/feature/main/widgets/main_active_list.dart';
import 'package:dromis/feature/main/widgets/main_available_list.dart';
import 'package:dromis/feature/main/widgets/main_completed_list.dart';
import 'package:dromis/feature/utils/navigable.dart';
import 'package:dromis/feature/info/info_screen.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';


import '../../core/injection/configurator.dart';

import '../pulse/pulse_screen.dart';
import '../ranking/ranking_screen.dart';
import '../utils/routes.dart';
import 'bloc/active_list_bloc/active_list_bloc.dart';
import 'bloc/available_list_bloc/available_list_bloc.dart';
import 'bloc/completed_list_bloc/completed_list_bloc.dart';

class MainScreen extends StatefulWidget implements Navigable{

  @override
  String getName() => Routes.mainScreen;

  @override
  State<MainScreen> createState() => _MainScreenState();
}

class _MainScreenState extends State<MainScreen> {

  bool activeBool = true;
  bool availableBool = true;
  bool completedBool = true;

  final activeListBloc = getIt<ActiveListBloc>();
  final availableListBloc = getIt<AvailableListBloc>();
  final completedListBloc = getIt<CompletedListBloc>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DRBgrForMain(
      child: SafeArea(
        child: Scaffold(
            backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
            appBar: PreferredSize(
              preferredSize: const Size.fromHeight(90.0),
              child: AppBar(
                backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
                toolbarHeight: 90, 
                foregroundColor: Colors.transparent,
                shadowColor: Colors.transparent,
                leadingWidth: 0,
                centerTitle: false,
                elevation: 0.2,
                title: DRAppbar(moneyCount: '4,50', onTapFaq: (){
                  // Navigator.pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(context, Routes.infoScreen, (route) => false);
                 
                 Navigator.push( // or pushReplacement, if you need that
                 context,
                 FadeInRoute(
                  routeName: Routes.infoScreen,
                  page: InfoScreen(),
                  ),
                  );
                }, onTapMoneyCount: (){}, onTapProfile: (){}),
              ),
            ),
            bottomNavigationBar: BottomAppBar(child: DRAppBarBottom(onTapPlay: (){}, onTapDashBoard: (){
              Navigator.push( // or pushReplacement, if you need that
                 context,
                 FadeInRoute(
                  routeName: Routes.dashboardScreen,
                  page: DashboardScreen(),
                  ),
                  );
            }, onTapRanking: (){
               Navigator.push( // or pushReplacement, if you need that
                 context,
                 FadeInRoute(
                  routeName: Routes.rankingScreen,
                  page: RankingScreen(),
                  ),
                  );
            }, onTapPulse: (){
              Navigator.push( // or pushReplacement, if you need that
                 context,
                 FadeInRoute(
                  routeName: Routes.pulseScreen,
                  page: PulseScreen(),
                  ),
                  );
            }, selectedPageNum: 1)),
            body: SingleChildScrollView(
                    child: Column(
                      children: [
                         Row(
                    children: [
                      const Spacer(flex: 1,),
                      Container(
                        height: 10,
                        width: 10,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(66),
                          color: DRColors.greenColor,
                        ),
                      ),
                      const SizedBox( width: 9, ),
                      InkWell(
                        splashColor: Colors.transparent,
                        highlightColor: Colors.transparent,
                        hoverColor: Colors.transparent,
                        onTap: () {
                          setState(() {
                            activeBool? activeBool = false: activeBool = true;
                          });
                        },
                        child: Row(
                          children: [
                            Text('ACTIVE',
                                style: TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                  fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w300,
                                  fontSize: 20,
                                ),
                            ),
                            const SizedBox( width: 7, ),
                            const SizedBox( width: 7, ),
                            Icon(activeBool? Icons.keyboard_arrow_down: Icons.keyboard_arrow_up,
                            color: DRColors.whiteTextColor,
                      ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                      
                      
                      const Spacer(flex: 9,),
        
                    ],
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(height: 5,),
                 ** ActiveListWidget(activeListBloc: activeListBloc, showAll: activeBool,),**
                  const SizedBox(height: 10,),
                  Row(
                    children: [
                      const Spacer(flex: 1,),
                      Container(
                        height: 10,
                        width: 10,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(66),
                          color: Colors.yellow,
                        ),
                      ),
                      const SizedBox( width: 9, ),
                      InkWell(
                        splashColor: Colors.transparent,
                        highlightColor: Colors.transparent,
                        hoverColor: Colors.transparent,
                        onTap: () {
                          setState(() {
                            availableBool? availableBool = false: availableBool = true;
                          });
                        },
                        child: Row(
                          children: [
                            Text('AVAILABLE',
                                style: TextStyle(
                                  color: Color.fromARGB(255, 255, 255, 255),
                                  fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w300,
                                  letterSpacing: 1,
                                  fontSize: 19,
                                ),
                            ),
                             const SizedBox( width: 7, ),
                             Icon(availableBool? Icons.keyboard_arrow_down: Icons.keyboard_arrow_up,
                             color: DRColors.whiteTextColor,
                      ),
                      
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                     
                      const Spacer(flex: 8,),
        
                    ],
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(height: 5,),
                  AvailableListWidget(availableListBloc: availableListBloc, showAll: availableBool),
                  const SizedBox(height: 10,),
                   Row(
                    children: [
                      const Spacer(flex: 1,),
                      Container(
                        height: 10,
                        width: 10,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(66),
                          color: DRColors.inputTextColor,
                        ),
                      ),
                      const SizedBox( width: 9, ),
                      InkWell(
                        splashColor: Colors.transparent,
                        highlightColor: Colors.transparent,
                        hoverColor: Colors.transparent,
                        onTap: () {
                          setState(() {
                            completedBool? completedBool = false: completedBool = true;
                          });
                        },
                        child: Row(
                          children: [
                            Text('COMPLETED',
                                style: TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                  fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w300,
                                  letterSpacing: 1,
                                  fontSize: 19,
                                ),
                            ),
                            const SizedBox( width: 7, ),
                      Icon(completedBool? Icons.keyboard_arrow_down: Icons.keyboard_arrow_up,
                      color: DRColors.whiteTextColor,
                      ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                      
                      
                      const Spacer(flex: 7,),
        
                    ],
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(height: 5,),
                  CompletedListWidget(completedListBloc: completedListBloc, showAll: completedBool)
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
        ),
              
              
            
          
      
    );
  }
}
```

`

***************************Here is the List code***************************____

```
`import 'package:dromis/feature/common/info_buttons_card/dr_info_cards_active.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_bloc/flutter_bloc.dart';

import '../bloc/active_list_bloc/active_list_bloc.dart';
import '../bloc/active_list_bloc/active_list_event.dart';
import '../bloc/active_list_bloc/active_list_state.dart';

class ActiveListWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final ActiveListBloc activeListBloc;
  bool showAll;
  ActiveListWidget({
    super.key,
    required this.activeListBloc,
    required this.showAll,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocProvider<ActiveListBloc>.value(
      value: activeListBloc..add(GetActiveListEvent()),
      child: BlocBuilder<ActiveListBloc, ActiveListState>(
        builder: (context, state) {
          if (state is ActiveListLoadedState) {
            return state.list.data?.isEmpty ?? true
                ? const SizedBox()
                : 
                      ListView.separated(
                        physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10),
                        itemCount: showAll? 2:state.list.data!.length,
                        shrinkWrap: true,
                        separatorBuilder: (context, index) {
                          return const SizedBox(
                            height: 10,
                          );
                        },
                        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                          return DRInfoCardActive(
                              listdata: state.list.data?[index],
                            
                          );
                        },
                      
                    
                  );
          } else {
            return const SizedBox(
              height: 100,
            );
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
`
```

I need to know what is wrong. My assumptions:
This is not the container widget itself in which the data is because it worked correctly before. Most likely a problem in ListView. It also throws the following error:

`════════ Exception caught by widgets library Incorrect use of ParentDataWidget. The itss ══════════════════════════════`

Comment: try wrapping listview builder with expanded or flexible widgets .
In debug it have error that is why it show grey screen in release mode.

Comment: I tried this, it didn't work